# Unnecessary queries executed by gorm to insert data in database tables

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying my hands on golang and gorm for creating a new feature in my current project.

I have following database structure in MySQL.

[image]

**UserMaster** table is at the top of hierarchy and its primary key column is being referred by many other tables and they themselves use it as Primary Columns. **UserLogin** table is one of such tables. This is is not the perfect database design but this is the db structure I will be working on and there are no chance the structure can be changed.

Following are the model classes I have created for UserMaster and UserLogin in go.

```
type UserMaster struct {
    UserId      string    `gorm:"column:UserId;PRIMARY_KEY";size:20`
    CreatedDate time.Time `gorm:"column:CreatedDate"`
    IsActive    bool      `gorm:"column:IsActive"`
    UserLogin   UserLogin `gorm:"foreignkey:Id"`
}

type UserLogin struct {
    Id            string    `gorm:"column:Id;PRIMARY_KEY";size:20"`
    UserName      string    `gorm:"column:UserName;unique"`
    EmailId       string    `gorm:"column:EmailId;unique"`
    PasswordHash  string    `gorm:"column:PasswordHash"`
    PasswordSalt  string    `gorm:"column:PasswordSalt"`
    LastLoginDate time.Time `gorm:"column:LastLoginDate"`
}

func (UserMaster) TableName() string {
    return "usermaster"
}

func (UserLogin) TableName() string {
    return "userlogin"
}
```

What I wish is to create rows in both UserMaster and UserLogin tables via gorm just by saving fully populated instance of UserMaster.

And following is the code I wrote for this.

```
func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/ormsample")

    if err != nil {
        panic("Failed to connect the database.")
    }

    defer db.Close()

    createNewUser(db, "someuser009@yopmail.com", "j;dfasdasdf")
}

func createNewUser(db *gorm.DB, emailId string, password string) UserMaster {
    userId := createUserId()

    newUser := &UserMaster{}
    newUser.UserId = userId
    newUser.CreatedDate = time.Now()
    newUser.UserLogin = UserLogin{}
    newUser.UserLogin.UserName = emailId
    newUser.UserLogin.EmailId = emailId
    newUser.UserLogin.PasswordHash = password
    newUser.UserLogin.PasswordSalt = "SomeSalt"

    db.Debug().Model(&newUser).Create(&newUser)

    return *newUser
}

func createUserId() string {
    uuidWithHyphen := uuid.New()
    uuid := strings.Replace(uuidWithHyphen.String(), "-", "", -1)

    return strings.ToUpper(uuid[:12])
}
```

This whole thing works as expected, that means it is inserting records to both UserMaster and UserLogin table.

The problem is the way the gorm is performing this database operation. Following are the SQL queries being logged the terminal (coz I am using `Debug()` function on gorm db object).

```
INSERT INTO `usermaster` (`UserId`,`CreatedDate`,`IsActive`) 
    VALUES ('1601F7E41E29','2020-03-22 22:24:08',false) 

UPDATE `userlogin` SET `UserName` = 'someuser009@yopmail.com', 
  `EmailId` = 'someuser009@yopmail.com', `PasswordHash` = 'j;dfasdasdf', 
  `PasswordSalt` = 'SomeSalt', `LastLoginDate` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'  
  WHERE `userlogin`.`Id` = '1601F7E41E29'

SELECT * FROM `userlogin`  WHERE `userlogin`.`Id` = '1601F7E41E29' 
 ORDER BY `userlogin`.`Id` ASC LIMIT 1

INSERT INTO `userlogin` (`Id`,`UserName`,`EmailId`,`PasswordHash`,`PasswordSalt`,`LastLoginDate`)
VALUES ('1601F7E41E29','someuser009@yopmail.com','someuser009@yopmail.com',
 'j;dfasdasdf','SomeSalt','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

As you notice above gorm executes 2 INSERT, 1 UPDATE and 1 SELECT queries to insert into two tables while it should be only 2 INSERT queries executed.

I searched a lot about this on various forums of golang and gorm but did not find anything which can explain this behavior.

Any help/guidance/direction to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @All feel free to ask if you need sql scripts to create the database tables. I did not include them in the question to keep the length of the question moderate.

Comment: What happens if instead of leaving `newUser.UserLogin.Id` empty you set it to `userId` as well?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes.. I tried that too... but the behavior is unchanged. It still executes 4 queries.

Answer (score 1):

Gorm call this function before create

```
func beforeCreateCallback(scope *Scope) {
    if !scope.HasError() {
        scope.CallMethod("BeforeSave")
    }
    if !scope.HasError() {
        scope.CallMethod("BeforeCreate")
    }
}
```

Here if primary key already set then gorm try to update existing data using the given primary key. That's why extra query executed.
To solve this issue, use `UserId` as `foreignkey` for `UserLogin` which is primary key of `UserLogin` model so that gorm try to save child first then parent. Don't set primary key, use BeforeCreate hook to set

```golang
func (user *UserLogin) BeforeCreate(scope *gorm.Scope) error {
  scope.SetColumn("Id", ), createUserId())
  return nil
}
```

Models like:

```
type UserMaster struct {
    UserId      uint      `gorm:"column:UserId;PRIMARY_KEY;size:20"`
    CreatedDate time.Time `gorm:"column:CreatedDate"`
    IsActive    bool      `gorm:"column:IsActive"`
    UserLogin   UserLogin `gorm:"foreignkey:UserId"`
}

type UserLogin struct {
    Id            uint      `gorm:"column:Id;PRIMARY_KEY;size:20"`
    UserName      string    `gorm:"column:UserName;"`
    EmailId       string    `gorm:"column:EmailId;"`
    PasswordHash  string    `gorm:"column:PasswordHash"`
    PasswordSalt  string    `gorm:"column:PasswordSalt"`
    LastLoginDate time.Time `gorm:"column:LastLoginDate"`
}
```

Using both `Model(&user)` and `Create(&user)` not needed.
`Model()` mostly used before update existing data which may cause extra query. For only create you can try

```golang
db.Debug().Create(&newUser)
```

Gorm auto select Model  `UserMaster` from `newUser`

Comment: thank you for your answer. I can not change the datatype of PrimaryKey column as this is an existing database running in production and I am building my application on top of it. If Gorm can not solve this issue, is there any other ORM do you suggest which I can use for this?

Comment: I tried using `db.Debug().Create(&newUser)` too but that did not help. It still runs 4 queries.

Comment: You can try to create `UserLogin` and `UserMaster` separately.

Comment: Yes... I tried that.. it works as expected and runs only two INSERT queries. I wanted to avoid that coz creating a new user in the application would require to insert rows in 2-4 tables. I was hoping to get this done just by triggering one Create operation via Gorm. If nothing solves the issue, I will have to take multiple Create operation route. Thank you for your help Abinash.

Comment: Use BeforeCreate hook to set primary key that solve the issue. I updated my answer.

Comment: I solved the issue by different way. If removed `PRIMARY_KEY` declaration from `Id` property of `UserLogin` struct. Meaning not letting Gorm know that its a primary key column. With this change now I see only two INSERT query being exeucted.

Comment: But removing primary key declaration  may cause some problem with query in gorm

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I wonder why my answer not accepted. Goodluck !